# I want to create a horizontalscrollbar array through the designer Gui and not by programming in C#

Tags: arrays, horizontal-scrolling

I want to create a horizontalscrollbar array through the designer Gui and not by programming in C#

I even asked Chat GPT. It said to select all in the designer GUI by opening the VIEW\Other Windows\Document Outline and selct all the scrollbars by pressing CTRL, then to change their properties tin Modifers as Public.Unfortunately it did not work. Do you know why?

Note: Please answer the questione xactly and dont tell me to create a new instance from the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.